# How to judge the contour is line or curve by opencv?

Tags: image, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

[image: Test image]

This image have two contours. I can find both with opencv `findcontour` function. What I want to know is how to judge which contour is line and which contour is curve ? Can anybody please tell how to do it?

Comment: Define a line between the first and the last point of the contour and measure the average distance of all other points to the line. If the contour is a line, the average distance is close to 0.

Comment: what u can do is fit a line using first and last points of contour and check whether other points fall on it or not. You needn't check all points to ascertain this, you can simply pick every 'n th' point.

Comment: Why is it complex? Defining the line from two points is simple. Calculating the distance of a point to a given line is also straight-forward. You just need to sum the distance and divide by number of points.

Comment: If shapes are not filled (i.e. they are curves), you can find the centroid of the contour using [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments), and then perform a point-in-contour test for the centroid using [pointPolygonTest](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest). For the line, the test will say it's inside the contour. Of course, this alone is not reliable for complex contours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by assuming you have a line, and apply some basic algebra.

First find the slope of the line and the y-intercept.  The slope of a line is defined as the change in y divided by the change in x.  So given two points (x0,y0), (x1,y1):

```
slope = (y0-y1) / (x0-x1)
```

The y-intercept is found using the slope-intercept equation `(y=mx+b)` and solving for b:

```
y = mx + b
b = y - mx
```

So

```
y_intercept = y0 - slope * x0
```

Once you have the slope and the y-intercept, you just need to loop through the points of your contour and see if all of the points fall on the same line.  If they do, you have a line; if they don't, you have a curve.

Since I don't know what language you're working with, here is the whole process in pseudocode:

```
// First assume you have a line - find the slope and y-intercept
slope = (point[0].y - point[1].y) / (point[0].x - point[1].x);
y_intercept = point[0].y - (slope * point[0].x);

// Using slope-intercept (y = mx + b), see if the other points are on the same line
for (n = 0 to numPoints)
{
    if ((slope * point[n].x + y_intercept) != point[n].y)
    {
        // You've found a point that's not on the line - as soon as you
        // find a point that's not on the line, you know that the contour
        // is not a straight line
    }
}
```

Note that you'll be dealing with floating-point numbers here, so you'll have to take that into account in the `if` condition - you can't directly compare floating point numbers for equality, so you'll need to round them to some acceptable degree of accuracy.  I left that out to keep the pseudocode simple.

Comment: A few points: Using the first two points to define the line will probably to much noise because they are very close. Using the first and the last point should work better. Using 1D slope and intercept will not work for vertical lines. So it is better to define the line with 2D vectors (start point and direction) and then calculate the actual distance of points to the line.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but for the record:

Compare distance between first and last points against contour length.
If they are close then contour is line-like, otherwise it's a curve.